# Change socksport and listen address?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, security, linux, torsocks

Is it possible to change TorAddress and TorPort when using `apt-transport-tor`? I'm trying to use socksports listening on another machine on my network.

Answer (score 1):

The [`apt-transport-tor` documentation](https://github.com/diocles/apt-transport-tor) shows how to configure this.

You'd want to either edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or add a new entry under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` containing a line like the following:

```
Acquire::tor::proxy "socks5h://apt:apt@localhost:9050";
```

The line follows the same format as cURL's `-x` directive, I.E. `socks5h://username:password@host:port`

In this case the username and password are used for traffic isolation, so that APT doesn't share circuits with other things that may be using the Tor client.